# Equivalence between a charged rotating cylinder and a solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, rotational-dynamics

Suppose we have a cylindrical shell of radius $r$ with surface charge density $\sigma$. Then we start rotating the cylinder at an angular speed $\Omega$. You can show that in this case the surface current density on the cylinder is $\sigma r \Omega$.

Similarly, in a solenoid with loop density $n$ and current $I$, the surface current density can be thought to be $nI$, so you can use this to "convert" between a rotating cylinder and a solenoid. For example, the magnetic field inside the cylindrical shell must be $\mu_0 \sigma r \Omega$, because for the solenoid it's $\mu_0 n I$.

I was wondering if you could establish another relation between the solenoid and the cylinder if the solenoid has a resistance $R$. Based on the analogy, I imagine the resistance must be connected to the cylinder's moment of inertia, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: Would it not be akin to the friction of the cylinder (resistance to rotation)? In an electrical circuit with a given current, the resistance sets the rate work is done, so in the cylinder case there needs to be some sink of energy. Of course the magnetic field depends only on the current not the resistance of the circuit (the resistance just sets the work required to move that current).

Comment: The solenoid's resistance is the pd applied divided by the current flowing. But with the rotating charged cylinder there is no pd applied, so I don't see how you can give it an electrical resistance (or even an equivalent resistance).

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting thought. If you simply scale the radius without changing the wire (or thickness), the resistance will scale directly with radius (proportional to circumference) whereas the moment of inertia scales as radius cubed (circumference times radius squared). So there doesn't seem to be a simple relationship.

If you arranged to scale the cylinder thickness inversely with the radius, then both the resistance and the moment of inertia would scale as radius squared.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ampere's law, you will find that the magnetic field inside the rotating cylinder is uniform. With some fiddling, you will get that the magnetic field is equivalent to a solenoid with an infinite number of loops per length with a $\sigma r \Omega \mathrm{d}l$ current in each loop (a differential amount of current in each loop).

Comment: This answer does not address the OP's question about resistance.

Comment: In a solenoid, the voltage and resistance determine the amps/meter. In a charged cylinder, that's determined by the charge density and angular velocity. By the way, this analogy can be extended to a bar magnet where the field can be calculated by assuming an effective current flow around the perimeter.

Comment: The analogy is not perfect since the solenoid is a spiral and has a current along its length.